# Trouble finding content from python beautiful scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape [this page](https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/search/results?q=%22edith%20cowan%22) and to get the URL of the title of each article which is an 'h3' 'a' element e.g. the first result is a link with text "Functional annotation of a full-length mouse cDNA collection" that links to [this page](https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/article/021-211-986-094-957/main).

All that my search returns is '[]'

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = requests.get('https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/search/results?q="edith%20cowan"')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html5lib")
article_links = soup.select('h3 a')
print(article_links)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with this problem due to the fact that you were using the wrong link to get the article links. So I didn't quite a few changes and came up with this code *(Do note that I removed the bs4 module as it is not needed anymore)*:

```
import requests

search = "edith cowan"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}

json = {"scholarly_search":{"from":0,"size":"10","_source":{"excludes":["referenced_by_patent_hash","referenced_by_patent","reference"]},"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":f"\"{search}\"","fields":["title","abstract","default"],"default_operator":"and"}}],"must_not":[{"terms":{"publication_type":["unknown"]}}],"filter":[]}},"highlight":{"pre_tags":["<span class=\"highlight\">"],"post_tags":["</span>"],"fields":{"title":{}},"number_of_fragments":0},"sort":[{"referenced_by_patent_count":{"order":"desc"}}]},"view":"scholar"}

req = requests.post("https://www.lens.org/lens/api/multi/search?request_cache=true", headers = headers, json = json).json()

links = []
for x in req["query_result"]["hits"]["hits"]:
    links.append("https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/article/{}/main".format(x["_source"]["record_lens_id"]))
```

The `search` variable is equal to the term that you are searching for (in your case `"edith cowan"`). The links are stored in the `links` variable.

---

**Edit: How I did it**

So the main question might be where did I get the link from and how did I know what to include in the `json` variable. For this, I used a simple HTML intercepter *(in my case [burp suite community edition](https://portswigger.net/burp))*.

This tool showed me that when you visit this [URL](https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/search/results?q=%22edith%20cowan) *(the one that you used in your question to send the req to)* your browser sends a post request to https://www.lens.org/lens/api/multi/search?request_cache=true which then retrieves all the info of the [current page](https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/search/results?q=%22edith%20cowan). What concerns the json variable burp suite also shows you what packets are sent, so I copy-pasted them into the `json` variable.

for better visualisation, this is how it looked inside of burp suite:

[image: Burp Suite screenshot]

---

**Edit: Scanning all the pages**

In order to scan all the pages, you can use the following script:

```
import requests

search = "edith cowan" #Change this to the term you are searching for
r_to_show = 100 #This is the number of articles per page (I strongly recommend leaving it at 100)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}

json = {"scholarly_search":{"from":0,"size":f"{r_to_show}","_source":{"excludes":["referenced_by_patent_hash","referenced_by_patent","reference"]},"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":f"\"{search}\"","fields":["title","abstract","default"],"default_operator":"and"}}],"must_not":[{"terms":{"publication_type":["unknown"]}}],"filter":[]}},"highlight":{"pre_tags":["<span class=\"highlight\">"],"post_tags":["</span>"],"fields":{"title":{}},"number_of_fragments":0},"sort":[{"referenced_by_patent_count":{"order":"desc"}}]},"view":"scholar"}

req = requests.post("https://www.lens.org/lens/api/multi/search?request_cache=true", headers = headers, json = json).json()

links = [] #links are stored here
count = 0

#link_before and link_after helps determine when to stop going to the next page 
link_before = 0
link_after = 0

while True:
    json["scholarly_search"]["from"] += r_to_show
    if count > 0:
        req = requests.post("https://www.lens.org/lens/api/multi/search?request_cache=true", headers = headers, json = json).json() 
    for x in req["query_result"]["hits"]["hits"]:
        links.append("https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/article/{}/main".format(x["_source"]["record_lens_id"]))
    count += 1
    link_after = len(links)
    if link_after == link_before:
        break
    link_before = len(links)
    print(f"page {count} done, links recorder {len(links)}")
```

I added a few comments to the code to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thanks - so that works, but I am not sure why? Can you explain your solution to me a little?

Comment: Hey, I just edited my answer and added some explanation. If this helped could you possibly click on the green tick near the answer? thank you very much in advance

Comment: Oops my bad I meant grey tick :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I follow it. My plan was to use the requests/beautifulSoup method to iterate through the pages (which I am familiar with), but not sure I can work out how to do it with thi method. Are you able to suggest how to best iterate through each page of results to get links?

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot to explain one of the key points. the reason my method works is due to the fact that the response that the server sent in your case was in the form of a json string ( which is quite rare to be honest). the `.json()` that I put at the end of `req` converts the response into a real json string. In most cases you can use requests/beautifulSoup but not in this one as the response from the post is in the form of a json string (and doesn't have any HTML in it).

Comment: I added a new part to my answer, now you should be able to scan all the pages.